# Insert values from another Table in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to copy all column data to another table.I have created a new blank table.How to insert the values in it.I am avoiding writing the column name manually because it contain 35 column name in it.Sequence & name of column are same in both the table..?

Answer (score 4):

If the tables have the same columns and types, just do;

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f25f8/2).

Answer (score 2):

use following stcript:

```
INSERT INTO "table1" ("column1", "column2", ...)
       SELECT "column3", "column4", ...
          FROM "table2"
```

for more information see:
http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html

Answer (score 0):

```
create table2 

insert into table2
select * from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create table2 with columns and datatype for each column. If the columns match up exactly on both tables, then insert into table2 from table1

```
Create table table2(
column1 datatype, 
column2 datatype,
column3 datatype,
column35 datatype
}

INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find my verion . i had same column name in both tables

```
    INSERT INTO first_table 
            (column_1, 
             column_2, 
             column_3, 
             column_etc)

SELECT tab2.column_1 AS column_1, 
       10            AS column_2, 
       Getdate()     AS column_3, 
       'some_text'   AS column_etc

FROM   second_table tab2 (nolock)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into dbo.FolderStatus
(  
   [FolderStatusId],
   [code],
   [title],
   [last_modified]
)
select
[code],
[code],
[title],
[last_modified]
from dbo.f_file_stat
```