# SQL average from multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

How do I get the average from multiple columns?
 for example:

```
Columns:   ID 125Hz 250Hz 500Hz 750Hz 1000Hz 1500Hz 2000Hz 3000Hz 4000Hz 6000Hz 8000Hz
Values:    1  92    82     63    83    32     43     54     56     54     34      54
```

I want to get the average of all the columns except the ID. How do I do that?

Comment: Add the columns and divide by 11

Comment: So you can have column names starting with numbers... Learned something today.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos, with quoted identifiers you can even have almost the entire Unicode BMP, including space chars (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html). However, I find leading digits for object names highly irritating. Can easily be mixed with regular numbers and produce unexpected problems. Highly discouraged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manually add the columns since there's no available built-in functions for horizontal aggregation.

```
select (125Hz+250Hz+500Hz+750Hz+1000Hz+1500Hz+2000Hz+3000Hz+4000Hz+6000Hz+8000Hz)/11 as aveHz from table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL-SERVER you can use this

```
DECLARE @total int
DECLARE @query varchar(550)
DECLARE @ALLColumns VARCHAR(500)
SET @ALLColumns = ''

    ----Build the string columns
SELECT  @ALLColumns = @ALLColumns + '+' + '['+sc.NAME+']'
FROM sys.tables st
INNER JOIN sys.columns sc ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
WHERE st.name LIKE '%YOUR_TABLE_NAME%' 
AND sc.NAME LIKE  '[0-9]%';--[0-9]% just get the column that start with number
    ----Get the total number of column, 
SELECT @total = count(*) FROM sys.tables st
INNER JOIN sys.columns sc ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
WHERE st.name LIKE '%YOUR_TABLE_NAME%' 
AND sc.NAME LIKE  '[0-9]%';--[0-9]% just get the column that start with number

SET @query = 'SELECT SUM('+ SUBSTRING(@ALLColumns,2,LEN(@ALLColumns))+')/'
    +CAST(@total as varchar(4))+ ' AS [AVG] 
    FROM [YOUR_TABLE_NAME] 
    GROUP BY [ID]'

--SELECT @query 
EXECUTE(@query)
```

This will execute a query like this one:

```
SELECT SUM([125Hz]+[250Hz]+[500Hz]+[750Hz]+[1000Hz]+[1500Hz]+[2000Hz]
           +[3000Hz]+[4000Hz]+[6000Hz]+[8000Hz])/11 AS [AVG] 
FROM [YOUR_TABLE_NAME] GROUP BY [ID]
```

**UPDATE**

Add a column to store the avg, I called it [AVG] and chage the value of @query to

```
SET @query = '
CREATE TABLE #Medition (ID int,[AVG] decimal(18,4))
INSERT INTO #Medition (ID,[AVG]) 
SELECT ID,SUM ('+ SUBSTRING(@ALLColumns,2,LEN(@ALLColumns))+')/'
+CAST(@total as varchar(10)) 
+ ' AS [AVG] FROM Medition GROUP BY ID
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE_NAME  SET YOUR_TABLE_NAME.[AVG] = #Medition.[AVG]
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME INNER JOIN #Medition ON YOUR_TABLE_NAME.ID =#Medition.ID
DROP TABLE #Medition
'
```

Note: Build queries string is a little ugly

Comment: Is it possible to put the average value to an column?

Comment: I understood everything except the insert statement. Shouldn't it be 
INSERT INTO #Medition (ID, AVG)
VALUES and then the select statement?

Comment: Also I didnt understand what you meant by '+ SUBSTRING(@ALLColumns,2,LEN(@ALLColumns))+'
Am I just to add all the columns like this:
[125Hz]+[250Hz]+[500Hz]+[750Hz]+[1000Hz]+[1500Hz]+[2000Hz]
           +[3000Hz]+[4000Hz]+[6000Hz]+[8000Hz]?

Comment: the insert stament, it's just that way when you insert values from another table [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600774/insert-values-from-another-table-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: the [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) it's to remove the space and the `+` symbol at the begin of the string, play with the @query...uncomment this `SELECT @query` and comment `EXECUTE(@query)` and see the query string

Comment: The idea is get the columns name dynamic, for a variable number of columns

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(125Hz + 250Hz + 500Hz + 750Hz + 1000Hz + 1500Hz + 2000Hz + 3000Hz + 
4000Hz + 6000Hz + 8000Hz)/11 as averageHz from TABLE
```

Comment: Oh, michikot beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, without actually using the magic number `11`, be it a little more verbose.

```
WITH t1 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM myTable
    WHERE (...) -- Should limit result to 1 row
),
t2 AS
(
    SELECT col1 FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col2 FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    (...)
)
SELECT AVG(col1) FROM t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will display Average value of all that fields of each ID you have.

```
SELECT AVG(125Hz+250Hz+500Hz+750Hz+1000Hz+1500Hz+2000Hz+3000Hz+4000Hz+6000Hz+8000Hz) 
AS Average FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```